# How to redirect https:// to https://www using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url

I need to redirect https://, http:// to https://www using .htaccess.

This is my base url https://www.mysite.co.bw/ and I need to redirect https://mysite.co.bw/ , http://mysite.co.bw/ to base URL using .htaccess

I have done this site in CodeIgniter 3.

This is what I have done so far.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.co\.bw$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.co.bw/$1 [R=301,L]


# Your existing CodeIgniter rules
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

But Above code not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use somthinge like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```